# Storing and downloading Data in iOS Applications

Tags: sqlite, core-data, ios5

I am a bit new to iOS Development and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction regarding an application I am working on.

I am currently working on an application that will be displaying product lists and categories. The list is updated on a weekly basis (one every week).

I am now trying to decide two things:

1- What's the best method of storing this data, I am looking for a way that will allow me to replace the data in the application once every week.
2- Is it going to be beneficial to use CoreData? Note that I Only have Product Category, Product and Product Information entities.

Appreciate your support.

Comment: Just to clarify , I am researching wether XML files or SQLlite will be better to store the data. I will be storing basic information + an image for each product. The number of products is not expected to be more than 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Core Data. Because I know Core Data and am used to work with it. But this is clearly very much like using a chainsaw to cut a slice of bread.

As I understand, you're not familiar with Core Data. Maybe it's not the right tool for the job considering the learning curve.

In your case I would simply use JSON files as provided by the server.

That said, if your looking in Core Data anyway, any store will do, either atomic, XML or SQLite. The first two will load the whole data set in memory and queries will be done in memory as well. SQLite provides the benefits usually associated with databases, with a slightly increased complexity. A chainsaw.

Comment: I disagree in respect to the chainsaw and the slice of bread. I use Core Data whenever I can even if the model only consists of a class with three values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabrice, I think you cleared the whole matter to me :)

Comment: I have another question though regarding SQLite, Is it going to be possible to let the user download a new SQLite DB once a week?? Or am I going to have to use a file to download and then load it into the SQLite DB??

Comment: You can of course download a SQLite database file and use it right away. But Core Data uses its own schema so you'll need to import the data from the downloaded database into Core Data (if you use it). SQLite is kind enough to have a portable file format.

Comment: Thanks again for your support, I think I'm gonna read into SQLite with Core Data, seems like a good way to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Core Data. If you haven't worked with Core Data before, learn it. It's a great framework.